# Spring EhCacheCacheManager who to get EhCache object to query

Tags: java, spring, ehcache

java - Spring - ehCache

I am using spring ehcache implementation spring context gives me `Cache` object that does not have following method

```
 Query query = cache.createQuery();
```

Can some body advise how to `createQuery` from a `Cache` object.

Spring ehCacheManager beans

```
<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager"
        p:cacheManager-ref="ehcache" />
    <bean id="ehcache"
        class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean"
        p:configLocation="classpath:ehcache.xml" />

@Service
public class CacheServiceImpl implements CacheService {

    @Autowired
    EhCacheCacheManager cacheManager;

    @PostConstruct
private void init() {
    Cache cache = serviceCache = cacheManager.getCache("serviceCache");//Gives me Cache Object CacheObject does not have Query query = cache.createQuery(); method
     }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it

```
cacheManager.getCacheManager().getEhcache(name)
```